# Do we have the following property about positive integer sequences?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is a set of natural numbers (not including $0$).

Define $$S_{*} := \{s^2+t^2: s,t \in S\}$$

so that $S_{*}$ contains positive integers that are sums of two squares, where the square root of each such square belongs to $S$.

Do we have the following criteria;

$$\sum_{s \in S}\frac{1}{s} = \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{s \in S_{*}}\frac{1}{s} = \infty ?$$

$\textbf{Example:}$

If $S = \mathbb{N}$ the above logical identity holds as $\sum_{s \in S}\frac{1}{s} = \infty$ and $\sum_{s \in S_{*}}\frac{1}{s} > \sum_{p \text{ is prime and }1\mod 4} \frac{1}{p} = \infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, and $P=\{$all primes$\}$ provides a tidy counterexample: we know that $\sum_{p\in P} \frac1p$ diverges. However, given any $U\ge1$, the number of integers in $[U,2U)$ that are the sum of two squares of primes is at most $\pi(\sqrt{2U})^2$, since both primes must be less than $\sqrt{2U}$ individually; and
$$
\pi(\sqrt{2U})^2 \ll \biggl( \dfrac{\sqrt{2U}}{\log\sqrt{2U}} \biggr)^2 \ll \dfrac U{\log^2 U}
$$
by Chebyshev's bounds or the prime number theorem (where $\ll f(U)$ means $<Cf(U)$ for some constant $C$). Therefore
$$
\sum_{n\in P_*} \frac1n = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{\substack{2^k\le n<2^{k+1} \\ n\in P_*}} \frac1n \ll \sum_{k=2}^\infty \dfrac{2^k}{\log^2(2^k)} \frac1{2^k} = \frac1{\log^22} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{k^2} \ll 1
$$
converges. (The primes weren't special: any sequence that grows like $n(\log n)^\alpha$ with $\frac12<\alpha\le1$ would work just as well.)

The other implication does hold, since $s^2+t^2 \ge 2st$ and therefore
$$
\sum_{n\in S_*} \frac1n \le \sum_{s,t\in S} \frac1{s^2+t^2} \le \sum_{s,t\in S} \frac1{2st} = \frac12 \biggl( \sum_{s\in S} \frac1s \biggr)^2.
$$